# Google Script: setting decimals in table

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Im trying to write a script to make an invoice in Google Sheets and then export the invoice to a Document when its finished. I've gotten quite far now, but the only thing I don't know how to do is set decimals in a table I'm making in the sheet and putting in the document.
This is the table in Sheets:
[Table in Sheets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Asek.png)

And this is what it looks like right now in the document:
[Table in Documents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmmM5.png)

I want to set the decimals in the last two columns to 2 and the decimals in the first column to 0.

I've been using parseFloat().toFixed(), but that doesn't seem to be working in the way I'm using it. I don't know how to get started, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide [mcve]

Comment: I'm agree with Cooper. But just in case, probably if you will use `getDisplayValues()` instead of `getValues()` you will get what you want.

Comment: Don't forget to take the [tour] and read [ask] for ways in which you can improve your question. Also, please do not provide screenshots of things which can be [presented as text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) (e.g. with markdown formatting, such as tabular data).

Answer (score 3):

As Yuri Khristich mentioned, if you want to get the displayed values on the sheet, you only need to use `getDisplayValues` instead of `getValues`.

#### Script:

```
var getValues = range.getValues();
Logger.log("Logging getValues");
getValues.forEach(row => Logger.log(row));

var getDisplayValues = range.getDisplayValues();
Logger.log("Logging getDisplayValues");
getDisplayValues.forEach(row => Logger.log(row));
```

#### Difference:

[image: output]

#### Reference:

- [getDisplayValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalues)